# Android will treat fast single touch as move?

Tags: android, touch

I write a very simple android application, that I can draw something on the pad. Touch the screen with a finger, you will see a green ball, move your finger, you will see a red line.

But I found a very strange thing: If I touch the screen with two fingers one by one very fast, it will draw a line between them! (Imaging you are pressing two keys `jkjkjkjkjkjjkjkjkjkjkjkj` on the keyboard)

The key code is pretty simple:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            multiTouch = false;

            id = event.getPointerId(0);
            PointF p = getPoint(event, 0);
            path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            paths.add(path);

            points.add(copy(p));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            multiTouch = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                int tId = event.getPointerId(i);
                if (tId != id) {
                    points.add(getPoint(event, i));
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (!multiTouch) {
                p = getPoint(event, 0);
                path.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
            }
            break;
    }

    invalidate();

    return true;
}
```

The full source is here: https://github.com/freewind/TouchTest/blob/master/src/com/example/MyImageView.java

And it's a working demo: https://github.com/freewind/TouchTest

Or you can just download the signed apk on your android device, and test it yourself: https://github.com/freewind/TouchTest/blob/master/TouchTest.apk?raw=true

You can see in my code, I have checked if it's multi touch and disabled drawing on that case.

My android version is 4.0, and my code target is 2.3.3

There is a picture on my android pad:

[image]

You can see there are some lines but it should not be, there should be a green ball on the left of the red line instead.

I'm not sure why android treat fast single touch as moving, I considered 3 reasons:

1. My code has something wrong
2. Android sdk has something wrong
3. My android pad has something wrong, e.g. missing a ACTION_DOWN event

How to find out the real reason?

---

**UPDATE**

One of my friend used his android mobile(android 2.1) to test this app and found there is no red line, another used android 2.3.5 and found there are red lines.

Please review my code, I have checked multi-touch by `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN`, and will do nothing on `ACTION_MOVE` if there are more than 1 points. So the `id` of point is not needed. (Actually, in my first version of this code, I used `id` but have the same issue).

And I don't think this is an expected behavior, because it made the development of touching programs hard. I found this issue because in my another application(user can drag/zoom/rotate an image by fingers), the image sometimes "jump" on screen.

I even tried a popular game (Fruit Ninja) on my android pad and iTouch, and found android version has the issue but iTouch doesn't.

Now I'm sure there is something wrong (**missing an `ACTION_UP` event when the first finger ups**), but I still don't know what causes it. My android pad? Or Android sdk?

Answer (score 0):

That is way it works for multitouch. When you press fast android handle it as gesture, and you will have 2 pressed pointers. To avoid it try to handle action_up, or use action_pointer_down instead

Comment: This issue happens when `single-touch`. I've checked that if it's multi-touch then did nothing. Handles of `action_up` and `action_point_down` are not needed, since for `ACTION_MOVE`, it will only draw lines when there is a NEW FRESH single `ACTION_DOWN`.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the id of the touch , so that you will handle only the first touch alone.

alternatively , you can monitor all touches and handle them together .

Comment: In my first version I've used `id`, but had same issue. You can see in my code, I only draw lines in `ACTION_MOVE` if there is a NEW FRESH `ACTION_DOWN`. It can make sure the drawing finger is not changed.